# CSS transition not applied if display property also changes (but not transitioned)

Tags: css

I've got an element, when it's parent's class changes, gets different `display` and `width` properties.

I would like to transition just the `width` property, but the transition doesn't get applied if the display property changes - even though the display property isn't being transitioned.

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/B6k3j/.

You can see `.none-content` doesn't get any properties transitioned (I've also transitioned `background-color` for visual effect) because it is changing from `display:none` to `display:inline-block`.  The `.ib-content` element however, whose `display` property doesn't change, transitions fine.

**To be clear: I'm not trying to *transition* the display property, the display property just happens to be changing at the same time I want the transition to apply.**

Sidenote: I have an example using animations, but it has odd behaviour & I'd like to support IE9 if possible: http://jsfiddle.net/VeAy2/1/

Comment: You cannot transition the `display` property at all. So you would have to restrict the `transition:all`...perhaps like this - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/B6k3j/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transitions on the display: property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property)

Comment: @Paulie_D - your fiddle still doesn't work, and this isn't a duplicate because I explicitly stated I'm NOT trying to transition the display property.

Comment: @Pickle You cannot animate in other properties at the same time as display. Meaning you will need to either change the display, *then* transition the other properties or not have `display:none` at all

Comment: @ZachSaucier I believe you (and the example would confirm it) - but is there any documentation on why this is the case?  I don't see why logically this should be the case.

Comment: because you can't animate an element that has `display:none`. It takes time before you can animate anything that wasn't displayed

Comment: I wouldn't have thought the browser would consider the element to have display:none, as that property gets changed at the same instant the animatable property changes.